# Snowflake - accessing case-senstive variable with $

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowlake allows to define variables:

```
SET var = 1;
SHOW VARIABLES;
/*
name    value   type    comment
VAR     1       fixed   
*/
```

We could define second "case-sensitive" version:

```
SET "var" = '9';

SHOW VARIABLES;
/*
name    value   type    comment
VAR     1       fixed   
var     9       text
*/
```

Now trying to access both variables:

```
SELECT $var;
--1 

SELECT $VAR;
--1

SELECT $"var";
-- SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 7 unexpected '$'.
```

The only way I found to access "var" is by using:

```
SELECT GETVARIABLE('VAR'), GETVARIABLE('var');
/*
GETVARIABLE('VAR')  GETVARIABLE('VAR')
1                   9
*/
```

Is it possible to get `9` using `$var_name` syntax?

Comment: perhaps, don't create variables with the same name but different case, and thus just use the auto capslock shouting versions. Or don't rely on compilar rewrites, as the `$<token>` will just be a rewrite to the `GETVARIABLE(<token>)` version.  Dose `SELECT $'VAR';` work?

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim 
`Dose SELECT $'VAR'; work? ` Unfortunately no. `"perhaps, don't create variables with the same name but different case, and thus just use the auto capslock shouting versions"` Yes, that is always a solution. The question was intended to find a working counterpart. SET/GETVARIABLE pair works and allows to access both variables, so I thought that it is also true for `SET var/SELECT $var`.